# Angular function works on mozilla but not on chrome

Tags: angular

I want to have a page on my website where my team can go and copy the email template I made and send it to the clients. So they go on this page they press the button than they just paste on email.

My TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-email',
  templateUrl: './email.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./email.component.css']
})
export class EmailComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('contentToCopy', { static: true }) contentToCopy!: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  copyContent() {
    // Create a range and select the content in the DOM
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(this.contentToCopy.nativeElement);

    // Clear the previous selection, if any
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection) {
      selection.removeAllRanges();
    }

    // Add the new range to the selection
    if (selection) {
      selection.addRange(range);
    }

    // Execute the copy command
    document.execCommand('copy');

    // Remove the range from the selection
    if (selection) {
      selection.removeAllRanges();
    }
  }
```

And on HTML

```
<!-- Your Copy Button -->
<div style="width: 100%; margin: 40px auto; display: flex; justify-content: end;">
  <button (click)="copyContent()" style="margin-right: 60px; background-color: #2e862e; border-radius: 5px; border: none; color: #fff; font: 16px/20px Verdana; padding: 15px;">Copy to Clipboard</button>
</div>



<!-- Your HTML Content -->
<div #contentToCopy>




  <h1 style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333;">Hello, User!</h1>
  <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #777;">
    This is a simple HTML email.
  </p>
  <a href="https://www.example.com" style="background-color: #007BFF; color: white; padding: 10px 20px; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 4px;">
    Visit Our Site
  </a>


</div>
```

So i want this function to select the rendered content of the page, copy it, so than it can paste it on email.
For some reason it works on Mozilla but not on chrome. How can i make it work on chrome?

Comment: Chrome has a built-in debugger; have you tried using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `document.execCommand("copy")` has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) for quite some time.

There is a [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) which you can use instead.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this is how I resolved my issue. After receiving recommendations to use the Clipboard API, I made the following changes to my TypeScript method:

```
async copyContent2() {
  try {
    // Focus the document to ensure copying from the right context
    window.focus();

    // Convert all images to base64 before copying
    const images = this.contentToCopy.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('img');
    for (const img of images) {
      const imgSrc = img.getAttribute('src') || '';
      const dataURL = await this.imgToBase64(imgSrc);
      img.setAttribute('src', dataURL);
    }

    // Get the outerHTML of the element, capturing the entire styled content
    const htmlToCopy = this.contentToCopy.nativeElement.outerHTML;

    // Construct a ClipboardItem object
    const clipboardItem = new ClipboardItem({
      'text/html': new Blob([htmlToCopy], { type: 'text/html' }),
      'text/plain': new Blob([htmlToCopy], { type: 'text/plain' })
    });

    // Write the ClipboardItem to the system clipboard
    await navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItem]);

    // Notify user of success
    alert('Content successfully copied.');

  } catch (err) {
    // Notify user of failure and log the error
    alert('Failed to copy content');
    console.error('Failed to copy content: ', err);
  }
}
```

To ensure images are copied correctly, I converted them to base64 data URLs using the following function:

```
imgToBase64(imgSrc: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      if (ctx) {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        resolve(dataURL);
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Context not found.'));
      }
    };
    img.onerror = (e) => reject(new Error('Image load failed.'));
    img.src = imgSrc;
  });
}
```

This method ensures that the content, including images, is properly copied to the clipboard and can be pasted into an email or other applications without any issues.